# Pandas Read CSV Missing Rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a big CSV file containing 16M+ rows as shown below:

```
with open(r'file.csv') as fp:
    count = 0
    for _ in fp:
        count += 1
    print(count)

16817381
```

However, when I read it using `pandas.read_csv`, I only see 15M + rows

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv', low_memory = False, usecols = [0, 13, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11])
df.shape[0]

15234809
```

The file format quality is bad. It has 27 columns in total, but some rows have values in additional columns. I suspect this causes the error.

For example, I see below error if I don't specify anything in `usecols`:

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 27 fields in line 189, saw 28
```

I checked similar questions and tried adding arguments like `error_bad_lines=False`, but nothing works.

Can anyone please advise? Thanks!

Comment: CSVs can include multiline fields, if the field is encapsulated in quotes. This means that CSVs with encapsulated text fields will have fewer rows than the count of newlines in the file. Check your data for this condition.

Comment: If the format is not fixed, try reading the file with `read_fwf` method and check if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

def ReadRows(stream, max_length=None):
    #get data in rows from stream
    rows = csv.reader(stream)
    #set max length
    if max_length is None:
        rows = list(rows)
        max_length = max(len(row) for row in rows)
    for row in rows:
        yield row + [None] * (max_length - len(row))

with open('yourFile.csv') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(ReadRows(f)))
```